# Can hand-reliant stat monsters in Yu-Gi-Oh! be abusable?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

So, for clarification first, I'm talking about *Yu-Gi-Oh!* cards that gain attack based on how many cards you have in your hands.

Say if I had 3 "Slifer The Sky Dragon" copies and had a massive draw deck, I'd have the "Veil of Darkness"x3, "Pot of Greed"x3, a few draw spells, a few monsters with draw effects, and a bunch of DARK monsters.

Veil of Darkness lets me draw a card if I draw a dark monster in the draw phase, and is a continuous spell. If I have 3 Veils, I can draw 3 cards for discarding a single dark monster. If one of those 3 cards are a Pot of Greed, I can draw 2 more, but then I have an endless draw chain because of my various Pots and Draw spells.

This means that if my starting hand after summoning Slifer is 5 and I've drawn 21 cards total, I will have had a total of 26000 ATK on Slifer, making almost any attempts to win very slim.

The chances of my opponent having a set card like Magic Cylinder or some counter-effect monster are also nearly impossible. This means that a card like Ascension Sky Dragon are abusable by the same tricks, given that it doesn't rely on the Nordic Archetype and can easily be supported by Pots and various Draw cards.

Does anyone have a counter-argument?

Comment: This question seems more suitable for [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com).

Comment: First of all, you might be interested in [One Turn Kill](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/One_Turn_Kill#List_of_One_Turn_Kills) and [First Turn Kill](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/First_Turn_Kill). Next, depending on [Traditional](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Traditional_Format)/[Advanced Format](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_Format), you can't have more than 1 Pot of Greed on your deck. If ignoring all of the restrictions, it might be possible to be abused, but I don't have playing experience at all, so I can't say for the counter-argument...

Comment: Other than that, looks like [Slifer can have up to 40000 ATK on Traditional Format](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Tips:Slifer_the_Sky_Dragon).